# Why would Realm addOrUpdateObject cause a property to get set to nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, realm

I have a managed `Avatar` class and a managed `User` class. The `User` class has a reference to the `Avatar` class:

```
@interface User : RLMObject
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) Avatar *avatar;
...
```

The `Avatar` class looks like:

```
@interface Avatar : RLMObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *urlStr;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData *imageData;
@end

@implementation Avatar
+ (NSString *)primaryKey {
    return @"urlStr";
}
+ (NSArray *)requiredProperties {
    return @[@"urlStr", @"imageData"];
}
@end
```

There are cases where a I've fetched a new user (say, from the server) but to avoid re-downloading the avatar, I want to instead grab the existing one out of the database. Seems straightforward, but after getting the existing `Avatar` reference from the db (using `[Avatar objectWithPrimaryKey]`) and setting it as the avatar property on `User`, when I then call `addOrUpdateObject` on the Realm, the `avatar` property gets set to nil. No exception thrown or debug log, the property just goes from non-nil to nil. And sure enough the `User` reference is empty in the db although the `Avatar` table is still populated.

Some of the code:

Checking for extant avatar:

```
    if let avatarURLStr = user.avatarURLStr, let avatarURL = URL(string: avatarURLStr) {
        if let dbAvatar = Avatar(forPrimaryKey: avatarURLStr) {
            let newAvatar = Avatar(urlStr: dbAvatar.urlStr, imageData: dbAvatar.imageData)
            user.avatar = newAvatar
        } else {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOf: avatarURL) {
                let avatar = Avatar(urlStr: avatarURLStr, imageData: data as Data!)
                user.avatar = avatar
            }
        }
    }
```

Adding the user to the db:

```
            let realm = RLMRealm.default()
            realm.beginWriteTransaction()
            // user.avatar is non-nil here
            realm.addOrUpdate(user)
            // user.avatar is nil here
            try? realm.commitWriteTransaction()
```

I'm on Realm 2.1.1 for Objective-C (but the project uses both Swift and Obj-C).

Comment: I'm also wondering if it's OK to addOrUpdate a non-managed object which references a managed object. I've actually tried making a new Avatar object that's not managed and addOrUpating that, but I get the exact same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Oy…figured it out. I simplified things for the question a bit and it turns out that one of the objects I was updating had a relationship with another object that had a relationship with another object that had an avatar. And that avatar was nil.